# Interactive canvas vs render table in html. Which way is faster?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Which way will be faster and use less memory?
For now i have rendered dynamic `<table>` by jQuery. Sometimes it has around few thousand cells and it is working so slowly when i do events on it. Html2Canvas is taking alot time to render this table as image. So i wonder about use interactive canvas. 
Here is fiddle with script for generating table http://fiddle.jshell.net/j6G66/

Comment: Give us example, what kind of events? Try pagination, try infinite scroll, etc.

Comment: Also ask youself how user-friendly is a "table with a few thousand cells"? Is this really the best approach? Alos how are you rendering the table in jquery, many small DOM maniputlation or one big one? Many small maniputlations can slow down performance.

Comment: Adding class with different backgrounds, resize all table ( by resizing every single <td> width and hight i.e. +1px), html2canvas is very slow and ofcourse rendering this table. Yes, many small manipulations. Added fiddle with script for generate table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created two examples,

One that mirrors the way **you're** creating your table
**and that's by creating and appending jQuery object elements on *every* loop iteration:**

```
function createDynamicTable(rows, cols) {
  var table = $('<table />');
    for(var i=0; i<rows; i++){ // noprotect
        var row = $('<tr />');
        for(var j=0; j<cols; j++){
            var cell = $('<td />');
            cell.text("R"+i+"-C"+j);
            cell.appendTo( row ); // Appends here....
        }
        row.appendTo( table ); // Appends here....
    }
    $('#tableContainer').append( table );  // Appends here....
}
```

The second one uses a different way of creating a table, that is based instead on the principle of
**concatenating a HTML String representation of the needed elements**:

```
function createDynamicTable(rows, cols) {
  var table = "<table>";
    for(var i=0; i<rows; i++){
        var row = "<tr>";
        for(var j=0; j<cols; j++){
            var cell = "<td>R"+i+"-C"+j+"</td>";
            row += cell;
        }
        row += "</tr>";
        table += row; 
    }
    table += "</table>"
    $('#tableContainer').append( table ); // Append only once!
}
```

Now let's be humans and exaggerate a bit creating a table with 1000 rows and 10 cells in each running:

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
createDynamicTable(1000, 10); 
var total = new Date().getTime() - start;
```

And let's see the results:

```
IN-LOOP jQuery OBJECTS/EL. CREATION       vs.     IN-LOOP STRING CONCATENATION

              ~920 ms                                       ~130 ms
```

**[jsBin demo 1](http://jsbin.com/gaquw/3/edit)**                                                                    **[jsBin demo 2](http://jsbin.com/gaquw/6/edit)**

---

<sub>A (logical) *side-note* on the string concatenation:

**you'll not be able to keep copies of alive Objects** inside `data-*` attributes like i.e:</sub>

```
cell = "<td data-objectcopy='"+ myObject +"'>...</td>"
```

<sub>cause the object will result in String `"[object Object]"`, in contrast to jQuery's `.data()`:</sub>

```
cell = $("<td />", {html:"..."}).data("objectcopy", myObject );
```

<sub>where any further change to the object like: `$(td).eq(0).data().objectcopy.someProperty = "new value";` will keep it's reference to the original `myObject` object alive.</sub>

Comment: +1 for demonstrating that one DOM manipulation is close to an order of magnitute faster than than what is literally thousands of DOM manipulations. Even dropping down to 1 row, concatination is approx twice as fast as creating and appending each cell to the single row. Rough figures of 5ms vs 2ms.

Comment: @JonP thanks for your note! I tested creating 100,000 elements; 10,000 rows and 10 cells: 9200ms (almost 10s!!) vs only 410ms with concatenation (on my lousy configuration).

Comment: I started playing with big numbers as well. As you get into the big numbers, the concatination version scales very well, and it seems to be browswer rendering that becomes the bottle neck. That is purely from observation, didn't try any actual measurements! After about 5000 rows the repeated DOM manipulation version becomes almost unuseable.

Comment: @jonP exactly. Even if concatenation takes up `~400ms` for 100,000 elements, what we are actually waiting is the browser rendering the elements on page, which takes faster in the latter, in any case.

Comment: I edited my code. Old way: 7200 elements with `~3380ms` . String way: 7200 elements with `~2670ms`. 1s less. Not big difference like others had, but still better. Thanks for help :)

Comment: @snuuve you're welcome! If you could create a jsBin or jsFiddle demo with a *visual* example I might take a further look to improve it as much as possible.

Comment: I thought it's all about `background-image` in cells, coz half of them have it so in 7200 elements i need to render 3600 images (each of them has 9kb) but when i disable it, its no big difference. Also before draw every `<td>` I'm iterating by JSON array (has same size as last changed table) for some data to insert into new `<td>`. It's sth like back-up when im changing my table size.

Comment: @snuuve I'm almost sure it can all be brought down to 1s. Or even less. For example you dont even need to assign data to your elements. You can keep that data intact inside an Object... Really if I could see a demo of what you're trying I believe we could work out on performance or other ideas.